# Why is the ASP.Net SessionPageStatePersister.ControlState stored in Page.RequestViewStateString instead of in SessionState?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to understand exactly how the SessionPageStatePersister interacts with the web browser, ViewState, and SessionState.  I've been under the impression that using a PageAdapter which specifies the SessionPageStatePersister (rather than HiddenFieldPageStatePersister) will store all of ViewState into SessionState.

After inspecting the SessionPageStatePersister in Reflector I'm starting to question this assumption.  It appears that the SessionPageStatePersister.ControlState property is still stored in the RequestViewStateString (SessionPageStatePersister.ViewState is stored in SessionState), when viewing the SessionPageStatePersister's Save method.

Can anyone shed some light on this ControlState information isn't stored in SessionState as well?  It seems that the only data that needs to be stored in the RequestViewStateString is the date stamp for the SessionState key: `"__SESSIONVIEWSTATE" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Ticks, 16)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the control state stays on the page and rides up and down with the request/reponse by default. I agree that this seems pointless, but you can overcome this by add a flag to the browserCaps section in your web.config as mentioned in this article:

http://szokelizer.blogsome.com/2006/11/09/how-to-put-controlstate-into-viewstate-and-how-to-put-viewstate-into-session/

Check out the part toward the end for the info you need.

I suggested to the team that they turn this setting on by default. Maybe if you vote the issue up, they will! Here's the link for that:

http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41202-asp-net-webforms/suggestions/2454872-make-httpcapabilitiesbase-requirescontrolstateinse

Comment: Thanks!  I tested your solution and the __VIEWSTATE hidden field in the page is minimal now.  It does seem like this should occur by default.